# Resizing an image in canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I've been trying to take an image already on the page and change its source to the URL of a different image loaded via the FileReader api. The result is a blank image, white, though the dimensions appear to be ok. ShowImage() positions a box for cropping - another div, and then loads the file, then calls resize(). How can I get the image to actually display? Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

```
function showImage(files) {
    var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");
    buttons[buttons.length - 1].style.display = "none";
    var target = document.querySelectorAll("img");
    target = target[target.length - 1];
    target.className = "";
    target.onload = function() {
        var rect = target.getBoundingClientRect();
        var position = {
          top: rect.top + window.pageYOffset,
          left: rect.left + window.pageXOffset
      }; // center cropping box in image
        box.style.top = (position.top + rect.height/2 - parseInt(box.style.height)/2) + "px";
        box.style.left = (position.left + rect.width/2 - parseInt(box.style.width)/2) + "px";
    }
    var fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onload = function(e) {
         target.src = this.result;
         resize(); 
     };
    fr.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
}

function resize() {
    var orgImg = document.querySelectorAll("img");
    orgImg = orgImg[orgImg.length - 1];
    var canvas1 = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas1.width = orgImg.width/2;
    canvas1.height = orgImg.height/2;
    var ctx1 = canvas1.getContext("2d");
    ctx1.drawImage(orgImg, 0, 0, orgImg.width/2, orgImg.height/2);
    orgImg.src = canvas1.toDataURL("image/png");
}
```

**Update**

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/vvh59pyw/)

Though it's supposed to load locally, so not sure it could work as a fiddle.

Comment: Can you create a demo of your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is full of errors, that is one of the reasons it does not work.

After correcting the errors your logic is flawed in the way you respond to the image load and file load events.

Renaming `target` to `image`

Your file reader loads the image file and then sets the `image.src` to the loaded dataURL. Then you call resize, but the image has not loaded, setting the src begins a load.

```
var fr = new FileReader();
fr.onload = function(e) {
     image.src = this.result;
     resize(); 
 };
fr.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
```

The resize needs to be in the image.onload but you set the `image.src` to the content of the canvas you used to reduce the image size. This will trigger the image.onload event once more, which will call the resize event.

So to fix remove the `resize` from the file reader onload and put it at the end of the  `image` (aka `target`) on load function. But before you call that resize remove the onload event from the image so to stop it firing again.

Your code should look more like

```
// refactored target to image
src.addEventListener("change",showImage); // Add event listener here not in HTML
function showImage() {
    src.style.display = "none"; // hide the input
    const image = document.querySelectorAll("img").pop();  // get the image from the page
    image.onload = function() {  // set the onload event 
        const rect = this.getBoundingClientRect();
        const pos = {
          top: rect.top + pageYOffset,
          left: rect.left + pageXOffset
        }; 
        const boxSize = box.getBoundingClientRect();
        box.style.top = ((pos.top + rect.height / 2 - boxSize.height / 2) | 0) + "px";
        box.style.left = ((pos.left + rect.width / 2 - boxSize.width / 2) | 0) + "px";
        this.onload = undefined; // remove onload event to stop it firing again
        resize(this);
    }
    const fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onload = function(e) { image.src = this.result }
    fr.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
}

function resize(image) {
    const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    const w = canvas.width = (image.width / 2) | 0;
    const h = canvas.height = (image.height / 2) | 0;
    canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(image, 0, 0, w, h);
    image.src = canvas.toDataURL();  // "image/png" is the default so not needed as argument
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The main problem was indeed the image not being loaded before trying to resize. Your code certainly makes more sense.